# Importing cython function: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fun'

Tags: python, cython

I have written a small `cython` code that is

```
#t3.pyx
from libc.stdlib cimport atoi

cdef int fun(char *s):
        return atoi(s)
```

the `setup.py` file is

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("t3.pyx"))
```

I run `setup.py` using this command

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This gives me

```
Compiling t3.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing t3.pyx
running build_ext
building 't3' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-     prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-  strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c    t3.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/t3.o
t3.c:556:12: warning: ‘__pyx_f_2t3_fun’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int __pyx_f_2t3_fun(char *__pyx_v_s) {
        ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/t3.o -o /home/debesh/Documents/cython/t3/t3.so
```

When I run in the `python` interpreter it shows me

```
>>> import t3
>>> t3.fun('1234')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fun'
>>>
```

Comment: For future readers, you want to use `cpdef` not `cdef` if you want to import the function in a regular Python script

Comment: The chances are you should use `def` rather than `cpdef`. Either way the code inside the function is compiled for both and runs at the same speed. `cpdef` is _only_ useful in the small number of cases where you want to call a function in a performance critical loop in Cython _and_ you want the same function available in Python. Otherwise it's restrictive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is that you defined your method with `cdef` instead of `def`. `cdef` methods can only be called from `cython` code.

You can find detailed information in the [Python functions vs. C functions](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-functions-vs-c-functions) section of the docs.

> Python functions are defined using the def statement, as in Python.
>   They take Python objects as parameters and return Python objects.
>
> C functions are defined using the new cdef statement. They take either
>   Python objects or C values as parameters, and can return either Python
>   objects or C values.

and the important part:

> Within a Cython module, Python functions and C functions can call each
>   other freely, but only Python functions can be called from outside the
>   module by interpreted Python code. So, any functions that you want to
>   “export” from your Cython module must be declared as Python functions
>   using def.